# yarn android error: Execution failed for task ':app:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'.\

Tags: android, react-native, yarnpkg

I keep getting this error when i run yarn android. Ive tried so many different things and I dont know what to do:

```
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'.
> [CXX1429] error when building with cmake using /Users/devinclem/Documents/Cryannus/cyrannus-mobile/cyrannus/node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/cmake-utils/default-app-setup/CMakeLists.txt:
```

any help is appreciated